# How I can indent generated java code java?

Tags: java, indentation, pretty-print

I work in a small learning program that generates Java code from a picture. I hold my code in a StringBuilder. I wonder as I can give the text a normal Java code indentation. I could use some library, but not to format the source code, but the String that has generated Java code. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you just want to format some Java code you could open the source file in Eclipse, IntelliJ or another IDE and then define custom formatting.  The IDE would format the file automatically.

Comment: But it is not my source code indentation is a java code generated from a ready-made classes. This code is generated in a String variable

Comment: What are you doing with this `String` after formatting it?

Comment: Here's a hint for a simple strategy: you often indent after an enclosing character like an open parenthesis or open bracket, yes? Let's say your code already has newlines in the places that you want. Anytime you see a substring of code matching the regex `[\(\{]\n`, then over the course of some number of lines after that you'll add, say, four additional spaces before each line. When you see a substring matching `[\)\}]\n`, you'll then want to reduce the number spaces before each line by four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import com.github.javaparser.JavaParser;
import com.github.javaparser.ParseException;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.CompilationUnit;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String java = new String("public class ThisIsANonWellFormattedJavaClass {public static void main(String[] args){}}");
        CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(java.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(cu.toString());
    }
```

It uses a great Java parser library called `javaparser`

Comment: Yes but : japa.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "if" "if "" at line 1, column 259.
Was expecting one of:
    "abstract" ...
    "boolean" ...
    "byte" ...
    "char" ...
    "class" ...
    "double" ...
    "enum" ...
    "final" ...
    "float" ...
    "int" ...
    "interface" ...
    "long" ...
    "native" ...
    "private" ...
    "protected" ...
    "public" ...
    "short" ...
    "static" ...
    "strictfp" ...
    "synchronized" ...
    "transient" ...
    "void" ...
    "volatile" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "{" ...
    "}" ...
    ";" ...
    "@" ...
    "<" ...

Comment: can you put here the input for me to examine? seems like that there is a syntax issue in your class. copy-paste it to an IDE and see what the issues is.

Comment: Sure, the String that contain the code is this: if ( desicion ) {
Earth;
 }
 else {
Gear;
 }
  if ( desicion ) {
Printer;
 }
 else {
Cube;
 }
  if ((User   &&  Wrench   &&  Box ) || (a) || (b)) {
run;
sleep;
 if ( true ) {
fly;
 }
 }
 }
  if ((Package) && (Printer) && (Wrench)) {
Wrench;
 }
  if ((df) && (adasd)) {
morir;
 }
  if ( condition ) {
noooo;
 if ( desicion3 ) {
 if ( and ) {
comer;
 }
 }
 else {
Box;
 }
 if ( a>b  ) {
comer;
 }

Comment: this does not look like java code...

Comment: but the code i suggested can only parse correct java code

Comment: ahhh ok, I had not taken that into account. So thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if u are using netbean IDE use `ALT+SHIFT+F` to indent

Comment: Op is not trying to format the source code.